# Why is the value not updated to the view from within a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this html:

```
<form name="form" novalidate data-ng-submit="TradeDaysFormSubmit()">
    <div data-ng-repeat="tradeDay in tradeDays">
        {{ tradeDay }}
        <br />
        <div inline-calender class="trade-calender-box" date="tradeDay" data-ng-model="tradeDay"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

With this controller:

```
$scope.tradeDays = [];

$scope.tradeDays.push("31-01-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("28-02-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("10-03-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("11-04-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("12-05-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("13-06-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("11-07-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("23-08-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("14-09-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("30-10-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("22-11-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("23-12-2013");
$scope.tradeDays.push("31-01-2014");
```

And the directive:

```
app.directive("inlineCalender", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            date:'='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, modelController) {
            scope.$watch('date', function (newValue) {
                if (!_.isString(newValue)) return;

                dateparts = scope.date.split('-');

                var minDate = new Date(dateparts[2], parseInt(dateparts[1]) - 1, 1);
                var maxDate = new Date(dateparts[2], parseInt(dateparts[1]), 0);

                element.datepicker({ defaultDate: scope.date, hideIfNoPrevNext: true, minDate: minDate, maxDate: maxDate });

                element.bind("change", function (event) {
                    var currentDate = element.datepicker("getDate");
                    scope.date = currentDate;
                    modelController.$setViewValue(currentDate.toString());
                    modelController.$render();
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The view shows all my calenders, so far so good. But, when I change a date, the new value is not passed to the model. As you can see, in the HTML I have `{{ tradeDay }}`, but this value doesn't change when I select a date on my calender.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I've tried the model controller, and isolate scope with two-way binding, but neither did work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martijngr/Qvu5u/1/) When you click a date in the datepicker, the text above is not updated.

Comment: Can you prepare jsfiddle?

Comment: where is your $render method i dont see in the code

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal I don't have one..? How should that method look like and do I need it?

Comment: @mikach I've created a Fiddle. See my post

Comment: @Martijn your fiddle is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just a small mistake in your code you should be using dot in a model just change your code to below and it will work

> http://jsfiddle.net/Qvu5u/3/

Just use dot model like

```
$scope.tradeDays.push({date:'31-01-2013'});
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Update the link in answer where you will find detailed answer

Comment: So it had something to do with prototypical inheritance.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to deal with the isolated scope is **always have a '.' in your ng-models**.

You can remove the $watch to prevent $apply to trigger multiple times. (You can see that in your code if you log something before $apply)

The date change can be easily captured by the callback function of the calender, you can change the code to:

```
link: function (scope, element, attributes, modelController) {
    dateparts = scope.date.split('-');
    var minDate = new Date(dateparts[2], parseInt(dateparts[1]) - 1, 1);
    var maxDate = new Date(dateparts[2], parseInt(dateparts[1]), 0);
    element.datepicker({
        defaultDate: scope.date,
        hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
        minDate: minDate,
        maxDate: maxDate,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            modelController.$setViewValue(date);
            scope.date = date;
            scope.$apply();
        }
    });
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gU7Gt/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. That looks a lot nicer. The reason I used a watch was because there was an error indicating that scope.date was undefined. But I've refactered the code a couple times, so I can'r recall the exact situation.

Comment: What I find confusing, in other directive I have a `visible: '='` parameter in my isolated scope. And when I set this variable, it just works: `scope.visible = false`. And my popup disappears.

Comment: Angularjs's 2-way data binding is achieved by using prototype inheritance, so the model has to be an Object with __prototype defined. So just remember always have a '.' in your ng-models. This is the nature of Javascript, not Angularjs's fault for sure.